# XSL : Global variables to select parent element

Tags: xslt

I want to be able to change "VarName1" to select a different month and not have to add each as a separate block of code.
Here is an example of the xml data I have:

```
    <Year1998>
      <MonthJan>
        <Day1>1st</Day1>
        <Day2>2nd</Day2>
        ...
      </MonthJan>
      <MonthFeb>
        <Day1>1st</Day1>
        <Day2>2nd</Day2>
        ...
      </MonthFeb>
      ...
    </Year1988>
```

I have tried the following with "VarName1" as a global variable but it doesn't show the values stored:

```
    <xsl:variable name="VarName1" select="MonthJan" />
    ...
    <xsl:for-each select="Year1988">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$VarName1/Day1" /></td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This works, but I can't use a global variable:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Year1988">
      <xsl:variable name="VarName1" select="MonthJan" />
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$VarName1/Day1" /></td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Are you the author/creator of the XML? If yes, can you change it? Don't use element names like this, because they cause the trouble you have. `<Year1998>` should be `<Year num="1998">`, `<MonthJan>` should be `<Month num="1">`.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you show is a perfect example of how one can shoot themselves in the foot with bad design decisions.

You *can* make somewhat dynamic XPath by using the `name()` function:

```
<xsl:variable name="MonthName" value="'MonthJan'" />

<xsl:value-of select="//*[name() = $MonthName]/Day1" />
```

but this is klunky, unwieldy, and - at the bottom line - unnecessary.

I strongly recommend that you change your XML structure into something sane instead.

```
<Year num="1998">
  <Month num="1" name="Feb">
    <Day num="1">1st</Day>
    <Day num="2>2nd</Day>
    ...
  </Month>
  <Month num="2" name="Feb">
    <Day num="1">1st</Day>
    <Day num="2">2nd</Day>
    ...
  </Month>
  ...
</Year>
```

and things will become much easier to handle immediately.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try This**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:variable name="VarName1" select="Year1988/MonthJan"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Year1988">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$VarName1/Day1" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak Sir, I will take care next time post code with explanation. Thanks!!

Comment: ...huh? Add an explanation to *this* post.